# Wait for Promises to fulfill before push them into an array (Javascript Promises)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-storage

**Greetings Javascript developers**

I'm relatively new to Javascript and ReactJS and I'm still learning new things every day. Currently I can't get rid of a problem:

**My Component**

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('artworks')
        .doc(props.artworkid)
        .collection('images')
        .get()
        .then(images => {

            let arr = []

            images.docs.forEach(image => {

                arr.push({
                    thumbnail: getImageURL(`${ image.data().imagename }_200x200.${ image.data().imageextension }`),
                    fullres: getImageURL(`${ image.data().imagename }_2000x2000.${ image.data().imageextension }`)
                })

            })

        })
}, [ props.artworkid ])
```

**My helper function**

```
export const getImageURL = (filename) => {
    return firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(filename)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(response => {

            return response

        })
}
```

The problem is, that I always get an array full of Promises, which get fulfilled later:

```
[{
    "thumbnail": Promise,
    "fullres": Promise
}, {
    "thumbnail": Promise,
    "fullres": Promise
}, {
    "thumbnail": Promise,
    "fullres": Promise
}, {
    "thumbnail": Promise,
    "fullres": Promise
}]
```

My intention is to populate the array of objects (thumbnail and fullres image URLs stored on Google Firebase Cloud Storage) and render it as image gallery in this functional component.

**How can I wait for the Promises to fulfill first before I push them into an array or State? I guess it has something to do with async/await… but I can't wrap my head arout it. Is there anyone able to help me?**

[image: React / Javascript code]

Comment: Don't wait for the promises before pushing. *Do* push them into an array of promises, then just use `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('artworks')
        .doc(props.artworkid)
        .collection('images')
        .get()
        .then(images => {

            let arr = []

            images.docs.forEach(image => {
                const thumbnailPromise = getImageURL(`${ image.data().imagename }_200x200.${ image.data().imageextension }`)

                const fullresPromise = getImageURL(`${ image.data().imagename }_2000x2000.${ image.data().imageextension }`)

                Promise.all([thumbnailPromise, fullresPromise])
                    .then(values => {
                        arr.push({
                            thumbnail: values[0],
                            fullres: values[1]
                        })
                    });
            })

        })
}, [ props.artworkid ])
```

Comment: That's it! It was so simlple. Now I know also, that I have to dive deeper into asynchronous programming with Promises. Thank you!